# How do you repair weep hole flashing in a brick veneer?

Tags: brick, moisture, flashing, weep-hole

I have a 1950's home with a brick veneer and a crawlspace.  The flashing that routes water from behind the veneer to the weep holes has broken in spots over time due to the weight of the trash mortar that cured on top of it.  The breaks allow moisture to enter the crawlspace around the foundation.  It also allows rodents to access the wall cavity and gain access to the attic.  The flashing appears to be made of a black felt-like band. How can I repair this? I was considering expanding foam but I'm afraid that may defeat the weep hole system.

[Video demonstration of original construction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3w3RZq5DXw)

[image: Construction diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no "easy" method that works. You have to strip the bricks down to that level and replace the flashing. Of course, this makes it an excellent time to consider how much you are or are not in love with brick veneer, since that's removing most of it. If you use a more durable flashing (lead is nice) you might get more than 60 years out of it; of course, if you can get 60 years out of anything it's probably more than you personally need.

You might find considerable cost-benefit in a rigid-foam / stucco replacement for the brick veneer - your walls are likley poorly insulated circa 1950s, and that would add a great deal of insulation to them.